# Site suddenly displays "Site Not Found"

Tags: 404

We have a client website which we inherited from another agency. It came with EE 2.10.1. We are normally a Craft agency, so we aren't unfamiliar with the way EE works.

Last night, I got a message that our client site was down. When I looked at it, the site started returning "File Not Found". This website was working earlier this week. I can get into the CP just fine. The log shows that the last login from our client to add content was on the 3rd. All of our other websites are working fine.

Can anyone tell me how I can diagnose this issue so I can fix it? I'm not getting any errors or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check and make sure your /index.php is in place and configured correctly.

Comment: index.php is in place and seems to be configured.

Comment: try yoursite.com/index.php

Comment: That pulls it up. I replaced the .htaccess file, and the main page comes up, but the side pages do not. When I went into the config page in the CP, I tried to delete 'index.php' as the index page, as per instructions in documentation. It says that it saved the new configuration, but index.php is right back where it was.

I can't make any changes to the General Configuration. :/

Comment: Possibly an `.htaccess` issue, but it sounds like your `site_url` config is hard set. Edit this file: `/system/expressionengine/config/config.php` and look for that variable set their.

Comment: Figured out the save thing -- when we transfered the site, we had it configed to an IP address while we waited for the domain to transfer, and for some reason it was still holding. Logged into the CP through the IP address and was able to change it to the domain. (Don't know how that was overlooked.) -- Main page opens. Side pages still do not. :/ Looking at the old htaccess to see if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: it was an htaccess thing. Got it figured out. Had to use the query switch after .php. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] -- Thank you for your help. :)